# Azure Key Vault secrets with ServiceBusTrigger Attribute on Web App Jobs

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-keyvault, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues, azure-secrets

I have Web App Job project which is configured to pluck messages from an Azure Service Bus and process them.

Presently I have a Functions class and a MessageReceived() method which is used as such:

`public async Task MessageReceived( [ServiceBusTrigger("some-queue", Connection="ServiceBusConnectionString")], SomeClass someInstance, int deliveryCount, DateTime enqueuedTimeUtc, string messageId, ILoggerlog) { //message procesing code }`

I also have all the KeyVault infrastructure in place, but I don't know how to get the Azure Secrets work with the [ServiceBusTrigger] attribute.

Normally I would use `@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=myvault;SecretName=mysecret)` in code, but I don't know how to use it with the trigger.

I have tried to pass the Secret to the Attribute, but that wouldn't work because attributes expect constant values.

Any concrete examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

- Well, you can directly save the reference of the key vault secret in the application settings in the following format

```
@Microsoft.KeyVault(VaultName=<Keyvault name>;SecretName=<Secret Name> ;  SecretVersion = <Secret version >)
```

- The application settings are under the configuration tab

Here in code my connection string is set to name `connection` so we must use the same name for the key vault reference.

[image]

output of the service bus trigger:

[image]

Comment: I was specifically referring to the ServiceBusTriggerAttribute